# Just as a beginner in Javascript I'm trying to create a code to allow an object to move up and down the y and x axis with the appropriate

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-development

Just as a beginner in Javascript, I'm trying to create a code to allow an object to move across the y and x axis with the appropriate response to directional keys. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 Canvas, also what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to make the object move on a `<canvas>` element or change its DOM position, but I can help with keydown events.

Here's a code snippet you can use to load the event and handle it:

```
// Load a document key down event
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);

// Function to register and handle the event
function keyDown(e) {
    var k = e.keyPressed;
    if (k === 37) console.log("Left key");  // Or whatever code you have
    else if (k === 38) console.log("Up key");
    else if (k === 39) console.log("Right key");
    else if (k === 40) console.log("Down key");
}
```

Note that you will need to know the key codes for this to work.  I have written a small function that you can use to get the key code of a pressed key:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);

function keyDown(e) {
    document.write(e.keyCode);
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmxx7nbq/).
EDIT: For the fiddle to work, you may need to click inside of the "Result" window.

Since I don't know if you want DOM manipulation, a `<canvas>` method, or something else, all I can help you on is the key events.  However, I hope I've sent you in the right direction.  Good luck!